# What XSLT can I use to transform recurring complex nodes into separate fields based on a field inside the node?

Tags: xml, loops, xslt

I'm a total beginner and the application I'm using only supports XSLT.

I have the following XML file that I need to reformat into separate fields based on the 'fieldName' of the recurring record node. How can I achieve this?

Input :

```
<root>
<record>
      <fieldName>B</fieldName>
      <fieldValue>apple</fieldValue>
</record>
<record>
      <fieldName>A</fieldName>
      <fieldValue>mango</fieldValue>
 </record>
<record>
      <fieldName>C</fieldName>
      <fieldValue>orange</fieldValue>
</record>
</root>
```

Desired output:

```
<root>
  <A>mango</A>
  <B>apple</B>
  <C>orange</C>
</root>
```

Comment: Please ask a **specific** question about a difficulty you encountered when trying to accomplish this. Otherwise it looks like you're just looking for someone to write your code for you.

Comment: While asking a question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tried to implement it.
(3) Desired output.
(4) XSLT processor and its compliance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The straightforward approach to this is simply

```
<xsl:for-each select="root/record">
  <xsl:element name="{fieldName}">{fieldValue}</xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each>
```

(I'm using XSLT 3.0 text value templates here - in earlier versions of the language you would replace `{fieldValue}` by `<xsl:value-of select="fieldValue"/>`. It's always best to say which version of the language you are using. If the application you are using doesn't say, then it's probably the ancient 1.0, because if it were something more modern, they would want you to know.)

If the rules for different fieldNames are structurally dissimilar, then a better approach would be to have one template rule for each field name:

```
<xsl:template match="record[fieldName='A']">
  <A>{fieldValue}</A>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Still learning XSLT but this worked for me.